# NextJS TypeScript error when setting data to a useState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, prisma

I'm new to TypeScript, ReactJS, and NextJS and I'm getting the following TypeScript error.
I'm using NextJS 14 and server actions, and Prisma as the ORM to work on this university project.

```
Argument of type '({ _count: { comment: number; }; user: { userRole: { role: string; }; } & { id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; emailVerified: Date | null; image: string | null; password: string | null; ... 5 more ...; updatedAt: Date; }; comment: { ...; }[]; } & { ...; })[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<PostObject[]>'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<PostObject[]>'.
```

I need help with fixing this.

My codes are as follows.

**.tsx file** where I get the above error on `setData(allPosts)` method call

```
interface PostObject {
  id: string;
  userId: string;
  title: string;
  media: string | null;
  content: string;
  isHelpfull: number;
  notHelpfull: number;
  status: PostStatus;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  user: {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    emailVerified: Date;
    image: string | null;
    password: string;
    telephone: string | null;
    role: number;
    isTwoFactorEnabled: boolean;
    subscriptionId: string | null;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
    userRole: {
      role: string;
    };
  };
  _count: {
    comment: number;
  };
}


export const CommunityFeed = () => {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [data, setData] = useState<PostObject[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  const fetchPosts = () => {
    startTransition(() => {
      getAllPosts()
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.error) {
            toast.error(response.error);
          } else {
            const { allPosts } = response
            setData(allPosts)
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          toast.error("Something went wrong. Please try again!");
        });
    });
  };

return ('frontend code')

}
```

**getAllPosts** server action

```
export const getAllPosts = async () => {
  try {
    const allPosts = await prisma.post.findMany({
      where: {
        status: {
          in: ["NEW", "APPROVED", "EDITED"], // TODO: Remove NEW status
        },
      },
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: "desc",
      },
      include: {
        user: {
          include: {
            userRole: {
              select: {
                role: true,
              },
            },
          },
        },
        comment: true,
        _count: {
          select: {
            comment: true,
          },
        },
      },
    });

    return { allPosts };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return { error: "Error occurred when retrieving data!" };
  }
};
```

**Prisma Schema** file

```
model Post {
  id          String      @id @default(cuid())
  userId      String
  title       String
  media       String?
  content     String?     @db.LongText
  isHelpfull  Int         @default(0)
  notHelpfull Int         @default(0)
  status      PostStatus  @default(NEW)
  createdAt   DateTime    @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime    @updatedAt
  savedPost   SavedPost[]

  user    User      @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  comment Comment[]
}

model SavedPost {
  id     Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId String
  postId String

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  post Post @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([userId, postId])
}

model Comment {
  id        Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId    String
  postId    String
  parent    Int?
  status    CommentStatus @default(ACTIVE)
  content   String
  validity  Boolean       @default(false)
  createdAt DateTime      @default(now())

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  post Post @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id                    String                 @id @default(cuid())
  name                  String?
  email                 String?                @unique
  emailVerified         DateTime?
  image                 String?
  password              String?
  telephone             String?
  role                  Int                    @default(10001)
  accounts              Account[]
  isTwoFactorEnabled    Boolean                @default(false)
  twoFactorConfirmation TwoFactorConfirmation?
  accessLog             AccessLog[]
  child                 Child[]
  isPediatrician        Pediatrician?
  isAssistant           Assistant?
  posts                 Post[]
  savedPosts            SavedPost[]
  comments              Comment[]
  appointment           Appointment[]
  payment               Payment[]
  subscriptionId        String?
  createdAt             DateTime               @default(now())
  updatedAt             DateTime               @updatedAt

  subscription Subscription? @relation(fields: [subscriptionId], references: [id])
  userRole     UserRole      @relation(fields: [role], references: [id])
}

model UserRole {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  level     Int
  role      String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  User      User[]
}

.
.
.
// Other prisma models
```

How do I fix these errors (I have multiple errors with the same error type in different server actions and frontend )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your api response data is not matching with interface `PostObject`.
So before returning the data from `getAllPosts` method, make its properties matching with `PostObject` interface.

first, export the interface

```
export interface PostObject {
   ...
}
```

Now, import in the file where `getAllPosts` is present.

```
import { PostObject } from "/path-to-interface-file";
```

And define the return type of `getAllPosts` method:

```
export const getAllPosts = async (): { data: PostObject[] } => { ... }
```

And then create the data as array of PostObject type using response.